# Facebook login with Spring Security

Tags: java, facebook, spring-security

I have successfully logged in with Facebook Javascript SDK and in server side I have successfully loaded facebook User with http://restfb.com/, but how can I authenticate my user via Spring Security? Since my facebook user doesn't have username and password, I cannot user regular authentication method, so how can I authenticate this facebook user in my app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much of the actual implementation details, but I would have thought you want to use OAuth using your spring application as the consumer and facebook as the service provider.
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/index.html